# Random Characters in string python

Tags: python-3.x, string, random, generate

how can i make a program that will take a sentence like

`i can take you places you've never been before` to this [check photo as it wont let me add the aids code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB10M.png). Basically add extra random characters and words that i choose beforehand in random places

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share the code